# Estimate $\pi$ using the Shoelace formula.

Tags: geometry, pi

$$\pi \approx \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{5^{-k}}{2} \cdot \left|\sum_{i=1}^{4(k+1)} (x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i)\right|$$

**Derivation**

This [lemma](https://euler.genepeer.com/schinzels-theorem) states

> For any non-negative integer $k$, $x^2+y^2=5^k$ has $4(k+1)$ integer
> solutions.

For a circle, the area is given by

$$A = \pi r^2$$

For a polygon, the area is given by the [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)

$$A = \frac{1}{2} \left| \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i) \right|$$

When the lattice polygon closely approximates the circle, their areas are nearly equal

$$\pi r^2 \approx \frac{1}{2} \left| \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i) \right|$$

Substituting $n=4(k+1)$ and $r^2 = 5^k$, then as $k \to \infty$

$$\pi \approx \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{5^{-k}}{2} \cdot \left|\sum_{i=1}^{4(k+1)} (x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i)\right|$$

**Example**

For $k=4$, there are $20$ polygon vertices, $\pi \approx 3.0901699$

[image: k4]

For $k=3600$, ran a [C program](https://godbolt.org/z/7crrMG6P3), $\pi \approx 3.1415926$

**Question**

Is this a correct new method to estimate $\pi$?

Comment: yeah, as I commented in your previous post now you need to get some formulae for the $x_i,y_i$ solutions. It's possible to get some type of binomial sum expression using Gaussian numbers but you might be able to exploit symmetry and induction cleverly.

Comment: something like:
$$(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2 + (x_1x_2+y_1y_2)^2= (x_1^2 + y_1^2)(x_2^2+y_2^2) = 5^{2k}\implies |x_1y_2-x_2y_1| = 5^k\sin\alpha_1$$
could be useful where $\alpha_1$ is the angle between the two vectors etc. I am positive that if you only focus on the first quadrant (due to $\pm x, \pm y$ symmetry) and carefully write things down, you should be able to finish it.

Comment: My maths skills are very rusty (programmer by day, gamer by night), so I'm happy just to make small contributions for fun. Thanks for looking into this further!

Comment: makes sense. Roughly speaking, the sum is then $\sum_i\sin\alpha_i$ with $\sum\alpha_i\to\pi/2$ as $n\to\infty$ and a hand wavy way to finish is to see that this tends to $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin\frac{\pi}{2n} = \pi/2$ and that's how you get the $\pi$ there. Making it rigorous might take some annoying work though.